# How can I set the price column, to be the sum of all the tuples?

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

```
 CREATE VIEW NewPC3 AS
 SELECT Component.price, 
        Mainboard.name as mainboard, 
        CPU.name as cpu, 
        GPU.name as gpu, 
        RAM.name as ram, 
        Computercase.name as computercase
 FROM Mainboard, 
      cpu, 
      gpu, 
      ram, 
      computercase
   NATURAL JOIN Component
 WHERE mainboard.cpusocket = cpu.socket 
   AND mainboard.formfactor = computercase.formfactor;
```

"name" in all the tables, refers to name in component, which also holds the price for each component. I would like the price column, to display the sum of all the components in each tuple

A tuple should not be created, if the cpusocket in the table mainboard doesnt match the socket in the cpu table, and the same for the formfactor in mainboard and the formfactor in computercase

testdata and expected result: [http://imgur.com/bi4m9b1](https://imgur.com/bi4m9b1)

Comment: Unrelated, but: do **not** mix the outdated implicit joins and explicit joins. Use a proper JOIN for **all** tables (and besides: you are not joining the `gpu` and `ram` tables properly something that would not happen if you used the modern explicit JOIN syntax)

Comment: Really not clear. Post table schema along with sample data and desired result

Comment: component: name, kind, price

gpu: name, speed, vram

cpu: name, socket, speed

computercase: name, formfactor

mainboard: name, formfactor, cpusocket, hasgraphics, ramtype

RAM: name, type, size


I wish the new view to show a tuples with one of each component, and the sum of the price of each component in the last column. Also the tuples made, should follow the constraint (cpusocket from mainboard has to be the same as the socket in cpu and the formfactor of the mainboard, has to be the same as the formfactor of the computercase)

Comment: could you please post the desired output with some data, this would help...

Comment: http://imgur.com/bi4m9b1 This is the best example I could come up with: http://imgur.com/bi4m9b1

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer